# Jenkins build failed with IOException: Failed to parse changelog

Tags: java, jenkins, build

How to go about finding the root cause ? stack-trace below :

```
[workspace] $ /usr/atria/bin/cleartool catcs -tag XXXXX
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../XXXXsupport_2.2/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch XXXXsupport_2.2
load /vobs/XXXX
java.io.IOException: Failed to parse changelog
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild>.java:622)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)                   
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
Discard old builds...
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a fixed [JENKINS-33433](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33433) issue

> jobs fail to "parse changelog" for pull requests with "catch-up" merges from destination branch][1](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33433)

Fix should be included in the formal release of 5.2 in August 2017 or latest beta 5.1.0.2 (released to Jenkins experimental update center)